# How to add a new view to all existing filters?

Tags: google-analytics, filtering

I have about 15 filters. Manually adding the new view to these filters is cumbersome. Is there a way to automate that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the Filters section of the view, then select "Apply existing Filters"

[image]